# Notification image is visible only after device is connected to the system

Tags: android

I am creating an app in which i'm getting notifications with images using FCM and i'am downloading that image in asyncTask using JobDispatcher, but the problem is only notification is visible in notification tray not images, now if i connect the device to system it displays the image in notification tray.

Comment: what 'system' are you connecting to?

Comment: Connecting to system in which I'm developing to check the logcat @Mercato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself , actually there is a method of job which is setConstraints() and I put DEVICE_CHARGING in that , that is why the jobService called only after device is connected to any USB charger or system .